# JGIT validate if repository is valid

Tags: java, validation, jgit

Is there a method to kill a clone operation mid-stream?
I will just use the cloning to validate the repository?
Is there any other way to test if the remote url/repository is valid?

Comment: Could you hava a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13606879/640012). I think this is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: you can invoke 'git ls-remote <REPO_URL>' using JGIT. see at (http://superuser.com/questions/227509/git-ping-check-if-remote-repository-exists)

Answer (score 5):

you can invoke 'git ls-remote ' using JGIT. see at [here](https://superuser.com/questions/227509/git-ping-check-if-remote-repository-exists)

Sample code as below:

```
    final LsRemoteCommand lsCmd = new LsRemoteCommand(null);
    final List<String> repos = Arrays.asList(
            "https://github.com/MuchContact/java.git",
            "git@github.com:MuchContact/java.git");
    for (String gitRepo: repos){
        lsCmd.setRemote(gitRepo);
        System.out.println(lsCmd.call().toString());
    }
```

Comment: An answer consisting of only code is never an answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! @SubliemeSiem

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the following heuristic (to be improved further):

```
private final static String INFO_REFS_PATH = "info/refs";

public static boolean isValidRepository(URIish repoUri) {
  if (repoUri.isRemote()) {
    return isValidRemoteRepository(repoUri);
  } else {
    return isValidLocalRepository(repoUri);
  }
}

private static boolean isValidLocalRepository(URIish repoUri) {
  boolean result;
  try {
    result = new FileRepository(repoUri.getPath()).getObjectDatabase().exists();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}

private static boolean isValidRemoteRepository(URIish repoUri) {
  boolean result;

  if (repoUri.getScheme().toLowerCase().startsWith("http") ) {
    String path = repoUri.getPath();
    String newPath = path.endsWith("/")? path + INFO_REFS_PATH : path + "/" + INFO_REFS_PATH;
    URIish checkUri = repoUri.setPath(newPath);

    InputStream ins = null;
    try {
      URLConnection conn = new URL(checkUri.toString()).openConnection();
      conn.setReadTimeout(NETWORK_TIMEOUT_MSEC);
      ins = conn.getInputStream();
      result = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      result = false;
    } finally {
      try { ins.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore */ }
    }

  } else if (repoUri.getScheme().toLowerCase().startsWith("ssh") ) {

    RemoteSession ssh = null;
    Process exec = null;

    try {
      ssh = SshSessionFactory.getInstance().getSession(repoUri, null, FS.detect(), 5000);
      exec = ssh.exec("cd " + repoUri.getPath() +"; git rev-parse --git-dir", 5000);

      Integer exitValue = null;
      do {
        try {
          exitValue = exec.exitValue();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
          try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
      } while (exitValue == null);

      result = exitValue == 0;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      result = false;

    } finally {
      try { exec.destroy(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore */ }
      try { ssh.disconnect(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore */ }
    }

  } else {
    // TODO need to implement tests for other schemas
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This works well with bare and non-bare repositories.

Please note that there seems to be a problem with the URIish.isRemote() method. When you create an URIish from a file-URL, the host is not null but an empty string! URIish.isRemote() however returns true, if the host field is not null...

EDIT: Added ssh support to the isValidRemoteRepository() method.

Comment: the code used to detect if a local repo is valid or not isn't correct in all cases, it will return true even for a partially cloned repo in an invalid state. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586502/how-to-check-if-a-git-clone-has-been-done-already-with-jgit) answer for some code that will handle this scenario too.

Comment: This will return `true`: `new URIish(new File("/tmp").toURI().toURL()).isRemote()`, so at the very least one should do `repoUri.isRemote() && !repoUri.getScheme().equals("file")`.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a look at the JGit sources and there does not seem to be present a method to  check for the validity of the remote repo.

This is the `call` method of `CloneCommand`:

```
public Git call() throws JGitInternalException {
    try {
        URIish u = new URIish(uri);
        Repository repository = init(u);
        FetchResult result = fetch(repository, u);
        if (!noCheckout)
            checkout(repository, result);
        return new Git(repository);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new JGitInternalException(ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    } catch (InvalidRemoteException e) {
        throw new JGitInternalException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new JGitInternalException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

In order to get if the remote URL is invalid, when catching a `JGitInternalException` `e` you may get the actual cause with `e.getCause()` to look for `InvalidRemoteException` or even `URISyntaxException`, but as you pointed out you end up cloning if it is actually valid; the library does not allow you to interrupt the operation.

Delving more deeply into the JGit code, the `TransportLocal` class has the `open(URIsh,Repository,String)` method you could have used to check if an `InvalidRemoteException` is thrown, but its constructor is not public. A do-it-yourself solution is required, alas. You could maybe start from the contents of the `TransportLocal.open` method I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK JGit doesn't have an implementation of `git fsck` yet.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking, I'm using the following, more generic approach, to validate a remote repository (the code is in C#, but it shouldn't be hard to convert it to java).

```
public static bool IsValidRemoteRepository(URIish repoUri, CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null)
{
    var repoPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName()));

    Directory.CreateDirectory(repoPath);

    var git = Git.Init().SetBare(true).SetDirectory(repoPath).Call();

    var config = git.GetRepository().GetConfig();
    config.SetString("remote", "origin", "url", repoUri.ToString());
    config.Save();

    try
    {
        var cmd = git.LsRemote();

        if (credentialsProvider != null)
        {
            cmd.SetCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        }

        cmd.SetRemote("origin").Call();
    }
    catch (TransportException e)
    {
        LastException = e;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JGit is working on an implementation of the `git fsck` command, but this has not been released on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit) as far as I can see.

Example on how it will look like, check this [test case](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/b0695e5b7b639797280916201e49076784377bd5/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/dfs/DfsFsckTest.java).

```
@Test
public void testHealthyRepo() throws Exception {
    RevCommit commit0 = git.commit().message("0").create();
    RevCommit commit1 = git.commit().message("1").parent(commit0).create();
    git.update("master", commit1);

    DfsFsck fsck = new DfsFsck(repo);
    FsckError errors = fsck.check(null);

    assertEquals(errors.getCorruptObjects().size(), 0);
    assertEquals(errors.getMissingObjects().size(), 0);
    assertEquals(errors.getCorruptIndices().size(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

API for validating remote repositories

```
public boolean validateRepository(String repositoryURL, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    boolean result = false;
    Repository db = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File("/tmp"));
    Git git = Git.wrap(db);
    final LsRemoteCommand lsCmd = git.lsRemote();
    lsCmd.setRemote(repositoryURL);
    if (username != null && password != null) {
        lsCmd.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password));
    }
    if (null != lsCmd.call()){
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note : ls-remote api of jgit throws NPE which is known bug. So added the workaround as mentioned in the comments of the bug.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436695